# Can I use parameters in form validation?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement a simple form validation, but I can't make it work with parameters somehow.

This is the code for just one input:

```js
const firstName = document.getElementById("first-name");
const nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,15}$/;
firstName.addEventListener("blur", validate(firstName));

function validate(id) {
    let re = "";
    switch (id) {
        case firstName:
            re = nameRegex;
            break;
        case lastName:
            re = nameRegex;
            break;
        case email:
            re = emailRegex;
            break;
        case password:
            re = passwordRegex;
            break;
    }

    if (!re.test(id.value)) {
        id.parentElement.classList.add("error");
        id.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
        id.parentElement.classList.remove("error");
        id.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add("hide");
    }
}
```

It looks like the code can't tap into the id.value field.

For reference this code works fine:

```js
function validateFirstName() {
    if (!nameRegex.test(firstName.value)) {
        firstName.parentElement.classList.add("error");
        firstName.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
        firstName.parentElement.classList.remove("error");
        firstName.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add("hide");
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? (I only want to use vanilla JS)

Comment: `.addEventListener("blur", validate(firstName))` - This calls `validate()` with `firstName` as argument, and assigns the return value as a `blur` event handler.

Comment: You don't need a parameter for `validate()`. `this` in `validate()` will be the element that triggered the event.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can benefit from the fact that `this` in an event handler added with `.addEventListener()` will be the element that triggered the event.

Instead of `id` you can use `this` in `validate()`

```js
function validate() {
    let re = "";
    switch (this) {
        case firstName:
            re = nameRegex;
            break;
        case lastName:
            re = nameRegex;
            break;
        case email:
            re = emailRegex;
            break;
        case password:
            re = passwordRegex;
            break;
    }

    if (!re.test(this.value)) {
        this.parentElement.classList.add("error");
        this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
        this.parentElement.classList.remove("error");
        this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add("hide");
    }
}
```

Slightly reduced example:

```js
const firstName = document.getElementById("first-name");
firstName.addEventListener("blur", validate);

const lastName = document.getElementById("last-name");
lastName.addEventListener("blur", validate);

const nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,15}$/;

function validate() {
    let re;
    
    switch (this) {
        case firstName:
            re = nameRegex;
            break;
        case lastName:
            re = nameRegex;
            break;
    }

    if (!re.test(this.value)) {
        this.parentElement.classList.add("error");
        this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
        this.parentElement.classList.remove("error");
        this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add("hide");
    }
}
```

```css
.error { color: red }
.hide { display: none }
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    First Name: <input type="text" name="first-name" id="first-name" />
  </div>
  <span>lorem ipsum</span>
  <div>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="last-name" id="last-name" />
  </div>
  <span>lorem ipsum</span>
</form>
```

Comment: @NguyễnVănPhong How does your edit (format some words in bold) improve the answer?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the getElementById returns a HTMLInputElement and not a the actual ID of the element.

```js
const firstName = document.getElementById("first-name"); // typeof HTMLInputElement
```

As mentioned by the other comments, your event listener is bound to the return value of `validate(firstName)`, which is `void` or `undefined`.

What you need to do is tell the event listener to fire the function when the `blur` event is occuring on the element.

```js
firstName.addEventListener("blur", validate); // Bind your entire validate function instead of the return value
```

Now you must change the logic inside your validate function, to distinquish between the different inputs.

```js
function validate(event) {
  // event.target is your entire element
  // event.target.value is the current value
  // event.target.id is the string id ie. first-name

  switch(event.target.id) {
    case 'first-name'
      re = nameRegex; // Assigns your nameRegex
    break;
  }

  if(re === '') {
    return; // Do nothing as we have no regex to validate with
  }

  // Your other code here
}
```

Comment: The name of the parameter is misleading yes, but the function works as-is with DOM nodes.